# Avoid logging Swagger Endpoints when you implement HandlerInterceptor?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui

I have implemented `Spring Boot + springfox-swagger-ui` and `HandlerInterceptor` to log the request for my application. When I start my application following all **swagger related endpoint are getting called** and all those endpoint are logging into request shown below.

> /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/fonts/source-code-pro-v7-latin-300.woff2
>
> /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff2
>
> /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/fonts/source-code-pro-v7-latin-300.woff2
>
> /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff2
>
> .....
>
> .....

LogRequestInterceptor.java

```
@Slf4j
public class LogRequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        .................
        .................
        .................
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        printJsonReq(request, userIdentityService.getUserName(), response.getStatus(), getTime(request), handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        printJsonReq(request, userIdentityService.getUserName(), response.getStatus(), getTime(request), handler);
    }
}
```

How Can I prevent logging those requests in `HandlerInterceptors` `preHandle` and `postHandle` and `afterCompletion` methods ?

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa - I dont want to log any requests for Js, CSS file. How to skip it ?

Comment: This interceptor will log all requests including js, css, etc. The only way to exlude some resources should be inspect the path from HttpServletRequest object and exclude resources that you don't want to log.

One question: Why do you want to log all requests?

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa - Could you please show some code over my code? I only want to log all those requests which user executes

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa - Like this in preHandle `if(request.getRequestURI() != null && request.getRequestURI().contains("springfox-swagger-ui")) {
   return true;
  }`

Comment: Create a new private method with a HttpServletRequest parameter. Use this method to validate the request. Then, call this method on preHandle, postHandle and afterCompletion mehods in first place

Comment: Exclude all /js /css /webjar paths too

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa - Could you please show some code ? I will really help all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following link you can view an example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

I think that is usefull for your problem

Comment: This link shows how to add pattern to include the paths when filter will be executed

Comment: I already went through this link, but things are not clear from it on how to exclude swagger endpoints

Comment: Include the paths that you want to log:

registry.addInterceptor(taxiFareRequestInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/**");

And exclude patterns that you don't want to log:

registry.addInterceptor(taxiFareRequestInterceptor).excludePathPatterns("/css/**", "/js/**");